# Compiling PowerPC (e5500 family) with little endian in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, endianness, powerpc

I have PowerPC e5500 family based embedded board. I want to compile a linux kernel with Yocto. I want this kernel to be a little endian kernel. But when I try to enable little-endian option in kernel config (`make menuconfig`), there is only big endian option.

I made a little research. PowerPC arch mostly supporting big-endian. I want to ask this question, if is there any way to compile PPC kernel for little-endian, can anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux kernel only supports little-endian kernels on 64-bit Book3S processors (see `CPU_LITTLE_ENDIAN` in `arch/powerpc/platforms/Kconfig.cputype`), and it's only really supported for Power8 (ISA 2.07) onward. Embedded systems (Book3E-based, such as the e5500) are all big-endian only - at least as far as the kernel is concerned.